# How to extend cordova build.gradle to change repositories

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

### Problem

Due to a problem with `jcenter` repository I need to instruct gradle to use use maven repository. I could fix the problem changing the file `build.gradle`:

Original:

```
//...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    //...
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
//...
```

Modified:

```
//...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    //...
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
//...
```

Since this file is not versioned, and per [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#extending-buildgradle), the way to extend `build.gradle` is to create a `build-extras.gradle` file, I've done so and have tried to add the same content I've modified in the `build.gradle` file, like:

*build-extras.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    //...
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### Question

To sum up, changing the `build.gradle` file works but placing the same diffed content in `build-extras.gradle` it does not. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `platforms` and `plugins` folders (lets do everything from scrach so it's cleaner).
2. Do `ionic cordova platform add android`
3. Do `cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=15.0.0 --fetch`
4. Now finally you can do `ionic cordova run android` or `ionic cordova build android`

Comment: You have my attention :D

Comment: idk what you mean @a--m , the solution is there, I've edited it with what to do to solve it step by step

Comment: All I mean is that you have my attention, I'm now testing to see if it solves the problem. And just for the records, although it might solve my build problem to be honest I don't think it answers the question ;)

Comment: For my specific case the plugin does not fix the issue. Now it fails in a different way. I don't think this is the better medium to post logs. I'll try to follow the plugin page troubleshooting to see if it helps, regardless I know that editing the build.gradle file does fix the problem, so it would be nice to have a answer that tackles that directly.

Comment: I didn´t have to remove node_modules folder. Followed the other steps and could build the app. Also changed build.gradle at app level, in order to have google() before jcenter(). Seems to be an issue with jcenter repo. Thank you.

Comment: @JaquelinePassos thank you for your input, that is right what I've described in my question, when I change the `build.gradle` the build works fine, even without installing this plugin. The problem is that if you are using CI for the builds you problably can't change the `build.gradle` file since it's generated at each build. Hence my question here...

Comment: with this plugin you don't need to change anything at build.gradle, just reinstall android platform and then install the plugin. I haven't found any other solution except doing that change at build.gradle. I doubt there is any other solution also, at least an easy one. I highly dislike the idea of having to change gradle.build due to CI also or just bec it's annoying if you have to install android platform again for some reason